# PHP find parents of leaf and build tree

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, tree

I have a quite simple task but I lost somewhere. I have categories table with common structure: id, id_parent, some other fields less important. I need to build multidimensional array from parents to children nodes like this:

```php
array(
    'id' => 1,
    'id_parent' => 0,
    'name' => 'Main', 
    'children' => array(
        'id' => 2,
        'id_parent' => 1,
        'name' => 'Main-sub',
        'children' => array(
            'id' => 3,
            'id_parent' => 2,
            'name' => 'Main-sub-sub'
        )
    )
)
```

I have given id of category (e.g. id = 3). I need to find very first parent of this category and then build tree traversing down. I'm tried simplest method using if statement recursively, but order of array I got is reversed. This is how it looks like at this moment:

```php
public function getCategoryById($id)
{
    $branch = array();
    $data = $this -> db -> query("SELECT categories.* FROM categories WHERE categories.visible = 1 AND categories.id = {$id} ORDER BY categories.position -- LIMIT 1");
    if(is_array($data))
    {
        foreach($data as $item)
        {
            if($item['id_parent'] != 0)
            {
                // do it again recursively
                $parent = $this -> getCategoryById($item['id_parent']);
                $branch['parents'] = $parent;
                // lost here
            }
            // lost here also
            $branch[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
```

I have searched threads and found few questions similar to mine, but solutions doesn't work in my case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off with a function that finds all of the children for a category given an ID and returns the structure you are looking for.

```
public function getChildrenForCategory($id)
{
  $children = array();
  $data = $this -> db -> query("SELECT categories.* FROM categories WHERE categories.visible = 1 AND categories.id_parent = {$id} ORDER BY categories.position");
  if(is_array($data))
  {
    foreach($data as $item)
    {
        // do it again recursively
        $subChildren = $this -> getChildrenForCategory($item['id']);
        $item['children'] = $subChildren;
        array_push($children, $item);
    }
  }
  return $children;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for! I just added `if(!empty($subChildren))` statement to prevent empty children arrays in each element. Thanks again!